# Php how to select the time stored in database in time combobox

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I have the time combobox which is showing the time properly and storing in database.

How to select the time in that list which is stored in the database.

In the database the stored time is `02:30` and in this all times are there i want to select the `02:30` from this list this time list is automatically populated.

Any help will be appreciated.

**My Code**

```
<select name="open" class="form-control" style="width: 112px;">
<?php
    $start=strtotime('00:00');
    $end=strtotime('23:59');
    for ($halfhour=$start;$halfhour<=$end;$halfhour=$halfhour+30*60) {
printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',date('H:i',$halfhour),date('g:i a',$halfhour));
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: use a POST/GET array and query on that with a `WHERE` clause; if that's what the question is about.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well in the database the stored time is `02:30` and in this all times are there i want to select the `02:30` from this list this time list is automatically populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well i have found the solution.**

```
$user   =   mysql_query("
select * from timing where sr_id = '".$_GET['id']."'
");
$usert  =   mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
$open   =   $usert['open'];

$start=strtotime('00:00');
$end=strtotime('23:59');
for ($halfhour=$start;$halfhour<=$end;$halfhour=$halfhour+30*60) {

$ttt=date('H:i',$halfhour);

if ($open == $ttt){
printf('<option selected value="%s">%s</option>',date('H:i',$halfhour),date('g:i a',$halfhour));
}else{
printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',date('H:i',$halfhour),date('g:i a',$halfhour));
}
}
```

It will select the time stored in database from this timing list by using `$open` and making variable of `date('H:i',$halfhour)` from that time code `$ttt=date('H:i',$halfhour);` of inside if condition `if ($open == $ttt){` in that time code.

Inspired by **@Fred-ii-**